# How to get object name values from jquery data attribute without json

Tags: jquery

I can get data attribute info via jquery like this:

```
<div id="test" data-info="color:blue,device:tablet,fruit:apple">click me</div>

$("#test").click(function(e){
var info = $(this).data("info");
alert("info: "+info);

//info: color:blue,device:tablet,fruit:apple
});
```

But I need use that info data like this: (I guess like a array object?)

```
color = info["color"];
device = info["device"];
fruit = info["fruit"];

alert ("color: "+color+" device: "+device+" fruit: "+fruit);
```

This example for what I needed:

```
info = {color:"blue", device:"tablet", fruit:"apple"};
color = info["color"];
alert("color: "+color);
//color: blue
```

So I did try like this; (but i am getting undefined error)

```
<div id="test" data-info="{color:"blue", device:"tablet", fruit:"apple"}">click me</div>

$("#test").click(function(e){
var info = $(this).data("info");
color = info["color"];
alert("color: "+color); //color: undefined
});
```

How can I do this?

Please Note: I don't want use json data and I need keep plain data-info area like this: `{color:"blue", device:"tablet", fruit:"apple"}` or maybe without { and } characters if possible.

I am sorry for my bad English and if I used wrong title or question description, you can edit it.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use json, for which you have a builtin parser, you will have to parse it yourself. You can use regex or split the text by the commas, then each element by the semicolon, and assign each key and value to an object. If you use quotes and need a escape character, you'll have to parse the value char by char or with a unnecessarily complicated regex. I'd just use json, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If values are simple and do not include nested objects you can use this code:

```js
$("#test").click(function(e) {
  let info = $(this).data("info");
  let object = {};
  info.split(",").forEach((elem) => {
    const el = elem.split(":");
    object[el[0]] = el[1];
  })
  console.log(object);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" data-info="color:blue,device:tablet,fruit:apple">click me</div>
```

or you can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method instead of data-* attributes to store objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#test").click(function(e){
  var dat = $(this).data("info").split(',');
  var info = {};
  $.each( dat, function(index,value){
    var p = value.split(':');
    info[p[0]]=p[1];
  });
  console.log(info['color']);
});
```

This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pcnzLeyf/4/

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. Actually your code is more comfortable to my usage with ajax each (`$.each`) instead of `forEach((elem) => {` But both answers helped me a lot. I learned how can I create a object (`= {};`) and how can I add objects in foreach function. And learned what is: `let` and `const`.